# I'm using eclipse extension newWizard, how to set wizard dialog size in java?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, jface

I have a Custom Wizard class which extends Wizard and implements INewWizard.
Added this wizard class to wizard under eclipse's extension org.eclipse.ui.newWizard.
When I do, Ctrl+N and select something and click on next the size of the page is small, how do I customize the size?

Comment: The `WizardDialog` normally adjusts the size to match the controls in the page according to the page layout. Are you saying this isn't happening?

Comment: Wizard size is adjusted according to the page layout. But I want to increase the size of this page.

Comment: Well what is going to be in this extra space? Normally you specify width and height hints on the layout of the various controls in the page to make the controls bigger than their defaults.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally you specify width and height hints on the layout of the various controls in the page to make the controls bigger than their defaults.

You can also override the wizard page `setVisible` method and set the dialog shell size as the page is made visible:

```
  @Override
  public void setVisible(final boolean visible)
  {
    super.setVisible(visible);

    if (visible) {
      final Shell shell = getShell();

      final Point size = shell.getSize();

      final Point newSize = ... calculate new size

      shell.setSize(newSize);
    }
  }
```